# Алиасы webpack при создании проекта через create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, alias

Создал приложение через `create-react-app`
Как мне добавить **алиасы**, чтобы, например в `sass` вместо

```
@import "../../../../variables"
```

писать

```
@import "@variables"
```

И по такому же принципу импортировать компоненты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JS

Для алиассов в JS, думаю, вам нужно [эта документация](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) и [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack)

Пример вашего конфига для JS

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            '@variables': path.resolve('путь.до/папки1'),
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Даст возможность делать такой импорт

```js
import '@variables/style.scss';
```

При условии, что файл `style.scss` находится внутри `путь.до/папки1`

## SASS

Для `SASS` же можно воспользоваться опциями `sass-loader`

Подробнее об этом [тут](https://github.com/davibe/next.js-example-with-global-stylesheet/issues/3) и [тут](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/1325)

Пример вашего конфига для SASS

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    ...
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    includePaths: ['путь/до/папки2']
                        .map((d) => path.join(__dirname, d))
                        .map((g) => glob.sync(g))
                        .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
                }
            }
    ...
}
```

Даст вам возможность делать такой импорт в `.scss` файлах

```
@import '@variables/style';
```

При условии, что файл `style.scss` находится внутри `путь/до/папки2/@variables`

---

Заметьте, что с `JS` можно ппросто сделать алиас и указать путь, при том папка может называться по-разному

Однако с `SASS` вам нужно будет иметь название папки именно `@variables`, а лоадеру вы просто укажете кастомный путь до неё

## Изменение конфига

Спасибо [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за замечание

По дефолту `create-react-app` прячет от нас конфиг, что бы мы его не трогали, но есть как минимум 2 способа его изменить:

1. Использовать `npm run eject`, но это плохая практика и к ней стоит прибегать лишь в **крайнем** случае. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files)
2. Использовать [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired), который позволяет делать **надстройки** над базовым конфигом, без использования `eject`. Подробнее [тут](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/176/Customize-Create-React-App-without-Ejecting) и [в этом видео](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-customize-create-react-app-cra-without-ejecting-using-react-app-rewired)

---

Не забывайте заменять `module.exports = {` на `module.exports = function override(config, env) {` при использовании `react-app-rewired`

Comment: Хорошо расписал 

Comment: @Даниил спасибо :)

Comment: При использовании react-create-app - конфиг вебпака скрыт внутри, поэтому приведенные варианты не применимы без выполнений `eject`

Comment: @Grundy да, не учёл